# Create a new recent post widget

Tags: widgets

My goal is to create a new recent post widget, Wordpress has one by default and i know how to edit it, but i was thinking i want to let the user decide what recent post suits most to his needs.

Is there any way to create a new recent post Widget without overriding the wordpress default one?

Comment: Yes, there is. You should create a Widget on your own. https://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API

Comment: In gutenberg we have a latest post block present, use it for recent post display

Answer (score 0):

My widget was like this:

```
 public function __construct() {
    $widget_ops = array(
        'classname' => 'yggdrasil_widget_recent_entries',
        'description' => __( 'Your site&#8217;s most recent Posts.' ),
        'customize_selective_refresh' => true,
    );
    parent::__construct( 'recent-posts', __( 'Recent Posts' ), $widget_ops );
    $this->alt_option_name = 'yggdrasil_widget_recent_entries';
}
```

Below works as a new widget without overriding the default wordpress recent posts

```
 public function __construct() {
    $widget_ops = array(
        'classname' => 'yggdrasil_widget_recent_entries',
        'description' => __( 'Your site&#8217;s most recent Posts.' ),
        'customize_selective_refresh' => true,
    );
    parent::__construct( 'yggdrasil-recent-posts', __( 'Yggdrasil Recent Posts' ), $widget_ops );
    $this->alt_option_name = 'yggdrasil_widget_recent_entries';
}
```

to not override default recent post the only thing i have to do is not name it as 'recent-posts' on this line: `parent::__construct( 'recent-posts', __( 'Recent Posts' ), $widget_ops );`.

The error was there.

see more details at: https://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API